# Simplify $\sin[\cos^{-1}(\frac{3}{4}) - \tan^{-1}(\frac{1}{3})]$

Tags: trigonometry

I am trying to solve the following:

$$\sin\left[\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{3}{4}\right) - \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)\right]$$

but I have no clue.....  I used wolfram alpha and it says the solution is

$$\frac{3(-1+\sqrt{7})}{4\sqrt{10}}$$

and it says the method is by the use of the addition method of trig functions; I don't see how though.  Any hints would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: $\arccos\frac{3}{4}=\arctan\frac{\sqrt{7}}{3}$, $\arctan\frac{\sqrt{7}}{3}-\arctan\frac{1}{3} = \arctan(\ldots)$ and $\sin\arctan(s)=\frac{s}{\sqrt{s^2+1}}$, for instance.

Comment: Why the three downvotes and vote to close?  I'm fully prepared to edit or add to the problem if needed, however no one made any sort of recommendations or criticisms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

Apply the formula $\sin(A-B)=\sin A \cos B-\cos A \sin B$:
$$\sin\left[\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{3}{4}\right) - \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)\right]=\sin\left[\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)\right]\cos\left[\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)\right]-\frac{3}{4}\sin\left[\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)\right]$$

For the calculation of each of the terms: 
for example, $\sin\left[\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)\right]$, let $\theta=\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)$, this means $\cos\theta=\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)$, from this, you can draw a right triangle and arrive at $\sin\theta=\left(\frac{\sqrt{7}}{4}\right)$. This means $\sin\left[\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)\right]$=$\sin\theta=\left(\frac{\sqrt{7}}{4}\right)$. Similarly, you can calculate 
$$\cos\left[\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)\right],\sin\left[\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)\right]$$  Then you substitute them back and indeed you have your answer
$$\frac{3(-1+\sqrt{7})}{4\sqrt{10}}$$

Comment: Why does this answer have a downvote?  Is it wrong?  I don't see anything technically wrong with it. However feels the need to downvote could instead leave comments that point out possible errors.

Comment: I do not know why someone would possibly downvote me... For I think this solution to this answer is fairly detailed and I am quite certain it's a correct approach.

Comment: I upvoted.....  I'm going through the solutions more carefully right now.  But it looked good at first.  Seems like someone is just being a bully.... they don't like me asking a "stupid easy question" and I have shown "no work" so they down vote then they down vote anyone who tries to answer.  I've already shown some work, namely that it is likely that I should use the addition formula, and indeed this is what you have used.

Comment: @Clclstdnt yeah as long as my solution is helpful. Although this problem is not hard and you could have struggled a bit more with it :)

Comment: I could have and should have.....  It's also late in the semester, I'm stressed and tired.  I don't feel like this is a place I need to justify myself.  I feel if people want to answer, let them answer.... if they don't want to, then don't. But don't be sanctimonious about it.

Answer (score 1):

Let $a=\cos^{-1}(\frac{3}{4})$, $\cos a= \frac{3}{4}$

Let $b=\tan^{-1}(\frac{1}{3})$, $\tan b= \frac{1}{3}$

$\sin\left[\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{3}{4}\right) - \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)\right]=\sin(a-b)$

$\sin(a-b)=\sin(a)\cos(b)-\cos(a)\sin(b)=\frac{\sqrt{7}}{4}\times\frac{3}{\sqrt{10}}-\frac{3}{4}\times\frac{1}{\sqrt{10}}=\frac{3\sqrt{7}-3}{4\sqrt{10}}=\frac{3(-1+\sqrt{7})}{4\sqrt{10}}$

Answer (score 1):

Always sketch right angled triangle in  matters of inverse trig evaluation
$$ \cos^{-1} \frac34 - \tan^{-1} \frac13 $$
$$ \tan^{-1}\frac{ \sqrt7/3 -1/3}{1+\sqrt7/9} $$
$$ \tan^{-1}\frac{ \sqrt7 -1}{3+\sqrt7/3} $$
Find Hypotenuse by Pythagoras thm
$$ 7+1- 2\sqrt7 +7/9 +9 + 2\sqrt 7 = \frac{160}{9}$$
whose square root is
$$ \frac{\sqrt10 \cdot 4}{3}$$

Now find sine.. opposite side/ hypotenuse,

the WA result follows

Answer (score 0):

You need some ingredients here.
First, a formula for $\sin(\alpha+\beta)$. 
And then, you'll need to compute $\sin\cos^{-1} (3/4)$ and other expressions like that.

In order to so, draw a Pythagoras triangle in which an angle is such that $\cos\theta = 3/4$. Now compute $\sin\theta$. Good luck and  feel free to come at the comments for further guidance.